# Quotation marks for nicknames

Tags: grammar, names, quotations, quotation-marks, nicknames

E.g. "I get called Hitler in school." or "I get called 'Hitler' in school."?

Would quotation marks be needed for 'Hitler'?
What if it was an uncommon or nonsensical word like 'A123' or 'Gaylord'. Would the capital letter alone be enough to grammatically make its usage fine? What if the nickname is made up of multiple words like "Fatty Pig Face"?

Comment: FYI, [_Gaylord_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaylord) is an actual name, both as a given name and surname.

Comment: @oerkelens So is Hitler. Just because a name is real doesn't mean that it can't be a nickname for someone who doesn't have that name officially. 'Benny' is a real diminutive of Benjamin but it was a nickname in the UK for someone with learning difficulties because there was a character called Bennny with learning difficulties on a British soap opera.

Comment: The whole point is that if your nickname was made up of multiple words like "Fatty Pig Face", that would make no difference at all.

Is it not obvious that grammatically "I get called (anything)…" has no interest in nor place for what you happen to be called?

Quotation marks will always be needed for 'Hitler', for 'A123' or 'Gaylord'. Why is that difficult?

The capital letter alone would never be enough to make usage fine.

Comment: Further, how is that different from "I get called Hitler in class…" then is it not obvious "I get called Hitler in German class…" so clearly does not work, it screams out for quotation marks?

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of style, so the best I can do is record what some style manuals say about it, directly or indirectly. Having said that, all but one manual I consulted would recommend that you use the quotes of some sort there.

**Discussion**

The only style manual that treats this issue explicitly is [*the Associated Press Stylebook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465093043) (entry for *nicknames*):

> When a nickname is inserted into the identification of an individual, use quotation marks: Sen. Henry M. “Scoop” Jackson. Also: Jackson is known as “Scoop.”

[*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195161912), in its entry for *flail; flay*, gives the following example, which suggests it too prefers to put nicknames in quotes:

> "He was nicknamed 'the human locomotive' because of his ungainly style..."

In [*the Oxford Guide to Style*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198691750) we find the following, which suggests this guide would recommend against quotes in your case (p. 87, emphasis mine):

> A nickname can supplement or supplant the owner's original name: *the Yankee Clipper* (Joe DiMaggio), *the Sun King* (Louis XIV of France), *the Fat Controller* (Sir Topham Hatt), *Ernest 'Papa' Hemingway, Charlie 'Bird' Barker*. Through use it can eventually replace the owner's name, either occasionally (*Old Blue Eyes,Il Duce, The Wasp of Twickenham*), partially (*Fats Waller, Capability Brown, Bugsy Siegal, Grandma Moses, Malcolm X*), (*Howlin' Wolf, Muddy Waters, Meat Loaf, Twiggy*). **While no rules govern whether a nickname is put in quotation marks, the tendency is for quotation marks to be used more often when the nickname is inserted within or precedes another name, and less when used alone.**

*The Chicago Manual Style*, in its FAQ, [says](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0059.html)

> After using quotation marks at the first mention of a nickname in the text, you can drop the quotation marks for subsequent mentions. In the notes, however, use the quotation marks for every citation.

Comment: The use of quotation marks when nicknames are inserted into the name is common and useful, as it makes it clear that a nickname rather than a middle name is being given. Once the nickname is established it's almost invariably unnecessary to use quotes. +1

Comment: I suggest this is by no means a Question of style… rather of simple practical necessity.

Use whatever name you like and you will run into a situation where it can be distinguished by either quotation or capitalisation.

Why is it not obvious that quotation will always work, while capitalisation will sometimes fail?

Answer (score 0):

Quote marks cause all sorts of problems with computers (xref https://xkcd.com/327/).
Italicising a nickname should also be a reasonable solution.